# pcshow figure quality with subsequent fill3

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have noticed a weird behavior that I can't explain neither overcome. 
Suppose I want to plot a point cloud:

```
figure;pcshow(myPtCloud)
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to add a filled polygon to my point cloud:

```
x = [-2; -2; -2; -2];
y = [4; 5; 5; 4];
z = [-0.5; -0.5; 0.5; 0.5];
hold on; h = fill3(x, y, z, 'b');hold off
```

This results in:
[image]

So far so good. But if I instead do:

```
x = [-2; -2; -2; -2];
y = [4; 5; 5; 4];
z = [-0.5; -0.5; 0.5; 0.5];
hold on; h = fill3(x, y, z, 'b''FaceAlpha', 0.8);hold off
```

the result looks like this:
[image]

The figure does not look as nice anymore! Why? And what can I do about it if I want to plot a semitransparent polygon in my pointcloud?!

P.S. The point cloud can be downloaded [here](http://www.filedropper.com/myptcloud)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that in order to render transparency, MATLAB forces the renderer to be `opengl`  which can affect how things appear when renderered. You can check this by getting the [`Renderer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_renderer) of the current figure before and after plot setting the `FaceAlpha`.

```
get(gcf, 'Renderer')
```

As far as why your plot looks "not as nice". I'm guessing that you are referring to the jagged axes lines. This is controlled by the [`GraphicsSmoothing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_graphicssmoothing) property of the figure. Check that it is enabled and ensure that you are using a [graphics card that supports OpenGL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html).

> Axes graphics smoothing, specified as 'on' or 'off'. Smoothing reduces the appearance of jagged lines in an axes graphic. MATLAB applies a smoothing technique to an axes graphic (and the axes rulers) if GraphicsSmoothing is set to 'on', and either of these conditions is true:
>
> - The Renderer property is set to 'painters'.
> - The Renderer property is set to 'opengl' and your hardware card supports OpenGL®.

**Update**

If you're talking about the points being too small on the second one, you can increase the [`MarkerSize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html#input_argument_namevalue_markersize) when createing the `pcshow` object.

```
pcshow(myPtCloud, 'MarkerSize', 10)
```

Or after createing the plot

```
set(findall(gca, '-property', 'MarkerSize'), 'MarkerSize', 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, the used renderer is opengl before and after plotting with FaceAlpha. Also, GraphicsSmoothing is 'on'...

Comment: @user1809923 Did you check if hardware opengl is being used?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do that. I typed "opengl info" and it for example shows that GraphicsSmoothing is supported (am using Nvidia Quadro K4000 btw.)

Comment: @user1809923 Then it should be supported and you shouldn't have any issues. Are the jagged lines what you're referring to when you say "not as nice"

Comment: I might not understand what you refer to as "jagged lines". When you compare the two images of the ptcloud with the polygon, the first one appears nicer to me. I guess the points appear somewhat thicker...I'd like to keep it that way with a transparent polygon in the plot :)

Comment: @user1809923 Oh if that's what you're talking about, then adjust the `MarkerSize` based on my update.

Comment: hmm..1) I want to plot the polygon in an existing pcshow-plot, so I would have to change the MarkerSize after creating the plot. 2) Why in gods name would plotting a transparent 3d-polygon reduce the MarkerSize of my point cloud?

Comment: @user1809923 the transparent polygon doesn't change the `MarkerSize`. The same MarkerSize can appear as different physical sizes depending on the renderer and adding the polygon tweaks the renderer. If you set it to be larger, this will be respected when plotting the polygon so just change it when calling `pcshow`

Comment: Unfortunately, the appearance of the point cloud still changes when calling fill3 with FaceAlpha <1, even when using pcshow(myPtCloud, 'MarkerSize', 10). I guess I have not really figured out yet what exactly the renderer changes.

Comment: @user1809923 Did you try increasing the `MarkerSize` to an even larger value? I just picked 10 randomly.

Comment: Hey! Yes, tried 20 now. The effect is still there but not as apparent anymore. I guess I can live with that :) There is no way to keep the renderer the same before and after plotting the polygon, is there?